# jqplot enhancedLegendRendrer seriesToggle functionality override

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

I am trying to change the default functionality of enhancedLegendRendrer.js where in on clicking on the legend series that particular bar item in the graph gets visible/hidden.I want to change this default functionality, wherein if the user clicks on the legend series item only that series is displayed while rest of the bars are made invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Jumped the gun on the post and now cannot delete.  Thought the above was asking how to enable toggling on legend.  Anyway, for anyone interested:

https://bitbucket.org/jab/jqplot/src/edd2f5972593/examples/legendLabels.html